# Sync image position between my mobile app and web application

Tags: android, data-synchronization

I am building mobile application that allow users to create albums from their mobiles. An album page can have different layouts and each layout allows the user to add multiple images.

[[image: Screenshot of the design]]

The user can zoom in/out and move image (right, up, down, etc)

Images position should sync to web application.

I couldn't find efficient way to share exact position of images from mobile. How i can place images in specific layouts and get exact position of it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your post a bit, included the image and fixed some grammar. I also added another tag so more people with knowledge might see it. Good luck!